# How to pull docker image with nerdctl, Error Access Denied

Tags: windows, docker, antivirus, nerdctl

I installed nerdctl (and later docker for tests) on different Windows-systems to use docker container. When pulling an image the layers are loaded. Only problem is an consistent error "Zugriff verweigert" (english translation "access denied"):

```
level=fatal msg="failed to extract layer sha256:52f95138e5aada89f1df17f4d8a0ebe569ba8f696577424c79870d6006f665d4: Failed to safefile.OpenRelative failed in Win32: open \\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\containerd\\root\\io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.windows\\snapshots\\15\\Files\\Windows\\System32\\csrss.exe: Zugriff verweigert (0x1f) Files\\Windows\\System32\\csrss.exe: unknown"
```

I alredy checked the proxy. The download works.

### **Update**

The identified proble is the anti virus. It prohibits the acess to the file caus it's identified as a important system file. wsl has the same problem. Same result with docker community editon and containerd.

How to resolve it?

[image]